Automatically gathering .ifc files with MSBuild
I have two projects that both use C++20 modules made with Visual Studio 2022. One is a library and builds just fine. The actual executable project is where it gets complicated. For it to build successfully in need to provide the compiler with all .ifc files from the library project. I thought that having to add the path for each module file separately would be tedious and probably not the right way to go about it. So after a bit of research into how MSBuild works, I added these things to my project file:
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  ...

  <ItemGroup>
    <IfcFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)DirectControls\x64\$(Configuration)\*.ifc" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
    <JoinedIfcFiles>@(IfcFiles->'%(FullPath)', ';')</JoinedIfcFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...

  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      ...

      <AdditionalModuleDependencies>$(JoinedIfcFiles);%(AdditionalModuleDependencies)</AdditionalModuleDependencies>

      ...
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      ...
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>

The idea was to dynamically acquire all the .ifc files and pass them as additional module dependencies. However when I try to build it now I get an error telling me that it cannot open '(IfcFiles->'%(FullPath)', ''. So after that, I changed
<AdditionalModuleDependencies>@(IfcFiles);%(AdditionalModuleDependencies)</AdditionalModuleDependencies>

to
<AdditionalModuleDependencies>$(JoinedIfcFiles);%(AdditionalModuleDependencies)</AdditionalModuleDependencies>

I got told this:
error MSB4164: The value "@(IfcFiles);%(AdditionalModuleDependencies)" of metadata "AdditionalModuleDependencies" contains an item list expression. Item list expressions are not allowed on default metadata values.

So now I'm at a loss and don't know how to fix this.
I hope it's clear what I want but I'll happily answer any questions.
Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

The default delimiter for an Item list is ;. You don't need to specify it, i.e. use <JoinedIfcFiles>@(IfcFiles->'%(FullPath)')</JoinedIfcFiles>. Take note of the evaluation order. It's not what you expect. The IfcFiles item is defined after the JoinedIfcFiles property and after the ItemDefinitionGroup. The MSB4164 error exists because items are evaluated after item definitions.

An ItemDefinitionGroup is best used for setting default metadata. You can change the metadata of every member of an item collection without an ItemDefinitionGroup.

@JonathanDodds Thanks for the reply. The problem I'm still facing is that I can not deviate from using ItemDefinitionGroup as I'm using Visual Studio to build my projects and still use the property dialog. I assume I'm just dumb and completely missing something.

Visual Studio will not overwrite the project file. You can customize the MSBuild code in the project and still build in Visual Studio.
